# how to filter ng-reapet values according to my ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Beginner in Angular, so it might sound a little silly question, but couldn't find an answer yet.

I have two select boxes - 
one which describes a module which I use as `ng-model=module` (`[x,y,z]`).
The second one is an array which in each index I have an array with 3 attributes - id, name and module( `[1, "first", x]`)

I am using `ng-repeat` for my second select box and I want to filter according to the module and the third index.
Basically, it's something like that: `"option in options | filter: module === secondbox[2]"`, but obviously I'm doing something wrong, maybe by syntax.

Please assist me to execute it right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best to write a custom filter for this:

```
.filter('moduleMatch', function() {
  return function(items, module, itemIndex, moduleIndex) {
    let out = [];

    // make sure a filter value was supplied
    if (module) {
      items.forEach(i => {
        if (i[itemIndex] === module[moduleIndex]) {
          out.push(i);
        }
      });

      // return the items that matched the filter value
      return out;
    }

    // no filter value was supplied - return the unfiltered collection
    return items;
  }
})
```

Then use it in the second select:

```
"option in options | moduleMatch: module:2:2"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Eventually, succeeded on my purpose using `ng-if`